# Shapefile segments

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile that plots the river segments and I have another shapefile that plots the observation station locations along each river. How do I create a new shapefile that plots those rivers (and their names in the attribute table) but also includes the observation stations that each river segment is in between and puts that in the attribute table?

Comment: I should add that this is on QGIS.

Comment: Is the river segments geometry (shapefile) actually split up into individual segments, one per observation station? Or do you need to split the river shape up into segments? Click 'edit' and update your question, ideally with some description of the data structure you have.

Comment: I suppose the station locations have point geometry. You cannot create mixed geometry (linestring and point) in a shape file.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own post; instead [Edit] your Question to provide clarifications. The exact release of GIS software in use should always be part of the question body.